# In std::forward how does it accept rvalue?

Tags: c++, c++11, perfect-forwarding

Looking at Scott Meyer's *Effective Modern C++* pages 200-201, the suggested simplified implementation of `std::forward` could be (did see the proper implementation elsewhere):

```
template <typename T>
T&& forward(std::remove_reference_t<T>& param)
{ return static_cast<T&&>(param); }
```

And when accepting an rvalue Widget, it becomes:

```
Widget&& forward(Widget& param)
{ return static_cast<Widget&&>(param); }
```

Now, if you take that substituted code, and do:

```
struct Widget { };

Widget&& forward(Widget& param)
{ return static_cast<Widget&&>(param); }

template <typename T>
void G(T&& uref)
{ }

template <typename T>
void F(T&& uref)
{ G(forward(uref)); }

int main()
{
  Widget x;
  F(std::move(x));
}
```

What I can't wrap my head around, and didn't see a direct answer on SO yet, is: *in `forward` how does parameter `Widget& param` manage to accept `Widget&&` from F()?*  Normally gcc-5.0 would complain like so with non-template code:

> error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘Widget&’ from an rvalue of type ‘std::remove_reference::type {aka Widget}’

([Question #27501400](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27501400/the-implementation-of-stdforward) nearly touches the topic, but not quite.  It shows the standard as having both lvalue & and rvalue && versions.)

Comment: Named rvalue references are lvalues; real rvalues are accepted by a separate overload.

Comment: @T.C. That is precisely the aspect I was overlooking, thanks.

Comment: If it has a name, it's an lvalue. So `uref` is an lvalue.

Comment: @JasonM I have actually emailed Scott about the exact same issue, as I thought it is a mistake. He basically left out the rvalue overload since he couldn't think of any usage case for it. I recently asked about this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29859696/3093378)

Answer (score 0):

> "Named rvalue references are lvalues",

so example works fine as noted in a comment.

Nevertheless your code could be modified to

```
template <typename T>
void F(T && uref)
{
    G(forward(move(uref)));
}
```

which is accepted by another overload (compare):

```
template<typename T>
T && forward(typename std::remove_reference<T>::type & t)
{
    return static_cast<T &&>(t);
}


template<typename T>
T && forward(typename std::remove_reference<T>::type && t)
{
    static_assert(!std::is_lvalue_reference<T>::value, "T is an lvalue reference");
    return static_cast<T &&>(t);
}
```

The second overload will be used for rvalue. It works if `T` is `Widget` or `Widget &&` and the assert fails for `Widget &`.

Comment: Why would one pass an rvalue to `std::forward`?

Comment: @0x499602D2 Probably by accident. And if you do this, you get a static_assert error.