# Difference between std::forward implementation

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, std, lvalue-to-rvalue

Recently I've been trying to understand move semantics and came up with a question.

The question has already been discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27501400/the-implementation-of-stdforward).

I implemented the first variant and checked whether it returns l-value or r-value:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
T&& my_forward(T&& x) {
    return static_cast<T&&> (x);
}

int main() {
    int a = 5;
    &my_forward(a); // l-value
    return 0;
}
```

So if I pass l-value, it returns l-value (compiles, because I can take an adress from l-value) and if I do that:

```cpp
&my_forward(int(5)); // r-value with int&& type
```

My code doesn't compile, because my_forward returned r-value. In the question above they say that the difference between this implementation and standart one (with std::remove_reference and 2 different arguments with & and && respectively) is that my implementation returns l-value all the time, but as I've shown it returns both r-value and l-value.

So I wonder, why can't I implement std::forward like that? In what specific cases will it show difference between standart one? Also, why should I specify T as a template and can't let it define itself with argument type?

Comment: Why are you trying to take address of r-value reference?

Comment: @BlackMoses To check the r-valueness.

Comment: @LogicStuff Ah, okay, thought it was a misconception of `&` usage :)

Comment: to check whether it's r-value or l-value. Basically to prove wrong first answer in the linked post **The problem with the first is that you can write std::forward(x), which doesn't do what you want, since it always produces lvalue references.**

Comment: You really should be testing this with forwarding references - which you can only have with template parameters.  Testing in main with variables, you can not pass in forwarding references to your my_forward.

Comment: What about the answer to the linked question did you find unsatisfactory?

Comment: @Barry well I thought, hey, it works fine in arificial context, but they said it return only l-values, so I found it confusing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try hsing it like std forward in a real context.  Yours does not work;

```
void test(std::vector<int>&&){}

template<class T>
void foo(T&&t){
  test(my_forward<T>(t));
}

foo( std::vector<int>{} );
```

The above does not compile.  It does with `std::forward`.

Your forward does nothing useful other than block reference lifetime extension.  Meanwhile, `std::forward` is a conditional `std::move`.

Everything with a name is an lvalue, but forward moves rvalue references with names.

Rvalue references with names are lvalues.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I checked it with this [code](http://ideone.com/XPePam) and it seems I was wrong. I didn't check it in a real context, because I thought (teoretically) that those implementations were the same. I can't really understand what's the difference. Can you explain it?

Comment: And why exactly my implementation works like this? As we saw in the topic, it returns r-value, why doesn't it work then?

Comment: **Rvalue references with names are lvalues.**   Until you understand that you will remain confused.

Comment: I think I understand that. The thing I don't understand is why standart implementation:
 
    typename remove_reference<T>::type& t
works differently than T&& t. 
In function body it'll be lvalue anyway (because it has a name) the only difference is in the argument

Comment: @fminkin Take the types `foo`, `foo&`, `foo&&`, `foo const&` and feed them to `typename remove_reference<T>::type&` and `T&&` respectively.  Pay attention to the rules of [reference collapsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13725747/concise-explanation-of-reference-collapsing-rules-requested-1-a-a-2).  They work differently because they are very different expressions.  The standard one, for example, can *never* be an rvalue reference.  How could they be the same?

Comment: It seems, I miscomprehended reference collapsing rule, I'll fiddle with that types and figure everything out than. Thanks a lot for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, taking the address is not a useful operation in your context, because it looks at the wrong kind of value category:

- You can take the address of a glvalue, but not of a prvalue. A glvalue represents a "location" (i.e. where an object is), a prvalue represents "initialization" (i.e. what value an object has).
- You can steal resources from an rvalue, but not from an lvalue. Lvalue references bind to lvalues, rvalue references bind to rvalues. The point of `std::forward` is to cast an argument to an rvalue when an rvalue was provided, and to an lvalue when an lvalue was provided.

When `std::forward` returns an rvalue, it actually returns an xvalue, and xvalues are both rvalues and glvalues:

```
                    lvalue       f() for "T& f();",   decltype(f()) is T&
                  /
          glvalue
        /         \
  value             xvalue       f() for "T&& f();",  decltype(f()) is T&&
        \         /
           rvalue
                  \
                    prvalue      f() for "T f();",    decltype(f()) is T
```

Comment: I think you meant. "You can steal resources from an rvalue, but NOT from an lvalue."