# Accept all combinatorial possibilities for a set of object types as parameter to function in C++

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, variadic-templates, variadic-functions

Given three different empty `structs`, `A`, `B` and `C`, I want to have a function `foo` accept any combination of any number of these three parameters, e.g.:

```cpp
struct A {};
struct B {};
struct C {};

// Foo has a required parameter that must be the first one given. Anything else is optional.

foo(1);
foo(1, A{});
foo(1, B{});
foo(1, B{}, A{});
foo(1, A{}, C{}, B{});
```

I thought variadic templates and function overloading would help in this situation, so here's what I've tried:

```cpp
struct A {};
struct B {};
struct C {};

template <typename... ExtraParams>
void foo(int x, ExtraParams&&...)
{
  std::cout << "x = " << x;
}

template <typename... ExtraParams>
void foo(int x, A&&, ExtraParams&&... extra)
{
  foo(x, extra...);
  std::cout << " with A";
}

template <typename... ExtraParams>
void foo(int x, B&&, ExtraParams&&... extra)
{
  foo(x, extra...);
  std::cout << " with B";
}

// same for C
```

However, when calling `f(2, A{}, B{})`, only `x = 2 with A` gets printed. I think I undestand why this does not work, but I am not quite sure how I should actually be dealing with this situation.

**EDIT** The code I was testing against used rvalue reference for the type considered known, e.g.:

```cpp
template <typename... ExtraParams>
void foo(int x, A&&, ExtraParams&&... extra)
{
  foo(x, extra...);
  std::cout << " with A";
}
```

and this will generate the exact behavior I mentioned (I don't know why though).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is when you pass the parameters `extra` to other overloads of `foo` as `foo(x, extra...);`, they're [lvalues](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category#lvalue) and can't be bound to the rvalue-references like `A&&` and `B&&`.

(emphasis mine)

> The following expressions are lvalue expressions:
>
> - the name of a variable, a function`, a template parameter object (since C++20)`, or a data member, regardless of type, such as
>     std::cin or std::endl. **Even if the variable's type is rvalue
>     reference, the expression consisting of its name is an lvalue
>     expression**;

You should use [`std::forward`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward) to *forward* the parameters (as rvalues if the original arguments passed are rvalues, i.e. to take advantage of [forwarding reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Forwarding_references)). e.g.

```
foo(x, std::forward<ExtraParams>(extra)...);
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ps01bgN08NsY7kvx)

Comment: I have tried using `std::forward` in my code as well, but haven't posted it here on SO. However, I was not passing the template parameter `ExtraParams` to the call and was getting errors. Could you please explain why the template parameter cannot be deduced here?

Comment: @Victor `std::forward` is just designed that way, you have to specify the template arguments explicitly. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27501400/3309790) I asked before.