# Why doesn't my forward_ function work for rvalues?

Tags: c++, perfect-forwarding

I've understood how `std::move` works and implemented my own version for practice only. Now I'm trying to understand how `std::forward` works:

I've implemented this so far:

```
#include <iostream>


template <typename T>
T&& forward_(T&& x)
{
    return static_cast<T&&>(x);
}


/*template <typename T>
T&& forward_(T& x)
{
    return static_cast<T&&>(x);
}*/

void incr(int& i)
{
    ++i;
}

void incr2(int x)
{
    ++x;
}

void incr3(int&& x)
{
    ++x;
}

template <typename T, typename F>
void call(T&& a, F func)
{
    func(forward_<T>(a));
}


int main()
{

    int i = 10;
    std::cout << i << '\n';
    call(i, incr);
    std::cout << i << '\n';

    call(i, incr2);
    std::cout << i << '\n';

    call(0, incr3); // Error: cannot bind rvalue reference of type int&& to lvalue of type int.

    std::cout << "\ndone!\n";
}
```

Why must I provide the overloaded `forward(T&)` version taking an lvalue reference? As I understand it a forwarding reference can yield an lvalue or an rvalue depending on the type of its argument. So passing the prvalue literal `0` to `call` along with the `incr3` function that takes an rvalue reference of type `int&&` normally doesn't need `forward<T>(T&)`?!

- If I un-comment the `forward_(T&)` version it works fine!?
- I'm still confused about: why if I only use the `forward_(T&)` version does it work  for any value category? Then what is the point in having the one taking a forwarding reference `forward_(T&&)`?
- If I un-comment the version taking lvalue reference to `T&` and the one taking forwarding reference `T&&` then the code works fine and I've added some messages inside both to check which one called. the result is the the one with `T&&` never called!

  ```
    template <typename T>
    T&& forward_(T& x)
    {
        std::cout << "forward_(T&)\n";
        return static_cast<T&&>(x);
    }

    template <typename T>
    T&& forward_(T&& x)
    {
        std::cout << "forward_(T&&)\n";
        return static_cast<T&&>(x);
    }
  ```
- I mean running the same code in the driver program I've shown above.

Comment: [MCVE](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8a4499bf2d4e2fa6)

Comment: You don't need an overloaded version... the `forward(T&)` is the only version that you should have.   "As I guess a forwarding reference can yield an lvalue or an rvalue depending the type of its argument."  Nope, the kind of reference depends on its template argument not its argument.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Yes it works if I use the version taking an lvalue reference to `T` only but why then the standard added the version taking forwarding reference? `T&&`?

Comment: @Maestro See https://stackoverflow.com/q/27501400/580083. TL;DR: it forces you to provide an explicit template argument for `std::forward`. Live demo: https://godbolt.org/z/ed8GKb

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `T&&` reference stops being a forwarding reference if you manually specify `T` (instead of letting the compiler deduce it). If the `T` is not an lvalue reference, then `T&&` is an rvalue reference and won't accept lvalues.

For example, if you do `forward_<int>(...)`, then the parameter is an rvalue reference and `...` can only be an rvalue.

But if you do `forward_(...)`, then the parameter is a forwarding reference and `...` can have any value category. (Calling it like this makes no sense though, since `forward_(x)` will have the same value category as `x` itself.)

Comment: Please explain more I'm so confused about it.

Comment: @Maestro Edited. Is it better now?

Comment: I've edited my `call` function to call `func(forward_(a));, then func<T&&>(forward_(a));` but still the same error?!

Comment: @Maestro Yes, because doing `forward_(...)` without specifying the template argument is completely useless (the result has the same value category as the argument).

Comment: I've also used: `forward_<T&&>(a)` but still the same.

Comment: @Maestro Yes, in this case it's no different from `forward_<T>(a)`. I'm not sure how to explain it, because I don't know what you don't understand.

Comment: @Maestro Do you understand that if you do `int x; forward_(x);`, `T` gets deduced as `int&` and why that happens?

Comment: I think because `x` is an lvalue but the problem is if I do `call(forward_<T&&>(0), incr3);` doesn't work too!

Comment: I'm still confused about: why if I use the version of `forward_(T&)` only works for any value category? then what is the point in having the one taking a forwarding reference `forward_(T&&)`? I'm so sorry for bothering you.

Comment: @Maestro: The basic problem is that *inside* of `call(T&& a, F func)`, **`a` is always an *lvalue***.  Even if the parameter to `call()` arrived as an rvalue, once it comes inside and is given the name `a`, it is an lvalue.  `forward<T&&>(a)` is putting the category from lvalue back to the category it arrived with.  `a` is always an lvalue when it reaches `forward()`.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Thank you. That is what I guess so only the version `forward(T&)` then what is the point in having `forward(T&&)`?

Comment: @Maestro: [Daniel already answered that one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65098198/why-doesnt-my-forward-function-work-for-rvalues/65098363?noredirect=1#comment115088659_65098198) when you asked in a comment on the question.

Answer (score 1):

It is clear that you wander why having two versions of `std::forward`; one takes an l-value reference to the type parameter `T&` and the other takes a universal reference (forwarding) to the type parameter. `T&&`.

In your case you are using `forward_` from inside the function template `call` which has forwarding reference too. The problem is that even that function `call` called with an rvalue it always uses `forward_` for an lvalue because there's no way that `call` can pass its arguments without an object (parameter). Remember that a name of an object is an lvlaue even if it's initialized from an r-value. That is why always in your example `forward_(T&)` is called.

- Now you ask why there's second version taking forwarding reference?
  It is so simple and as you may have already guessed: it is used for r-values (the values not the names of those objects).

Here is an example:

```
template <typename T>
T&& forward_(T& x)
{
    std::cout << "forward_(T&)\n";
    return static_cast<T&&>(x);
}

template <typename T>
T&& forward_(T&& x)
{
    std::cout << "forward_(T&&)\n";
    return static_cast<T&&>(x);
}

int main()
{

    int i = 10;
    forward_(i); // forward(T&)  (1)
    forward_(5); // forward(T&&) (2)
    forward_("Hi"); // forward(T&) (3)
}
```